# Trouble selecting item from list in DropdownButton

Tags: flutter

I am having a problem, when I display the list and try to select an item it does not select anything, however, it is printing the ID but it is not showing me the name of the item that I select on the screen

This is my code that I am using.

```
                         DropdownButton(
                                value: null,
                                isDense: true,
                                hint: new Text("Seleccione Tipo Documento"),
                                items: dataTipoDoc.map((item) {
                                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                    child: new Text(item['nom']),
                                    value: item['id'].toString(),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (newVal) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _mySelectionTipoDoc = newVal;
                                  });
                                },
                                //value: _mySelection,
                              )
```

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can change `value` from `null` to `_mySelectionTipoDoc` 
code snippet

```
DropdownButton(
      value: _mySelectionTipoDoc,
      isDense: true,
      hint: Text("Seleccione Tipo Documento"),
      items: dataTipoDoc.map((item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(item['nom']),
          value: item['id'].toString(),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (Val) {
        setState(() {
          _mySelectionTipoDoc = Val;
          print(_mySelectionTipoDoc);
        });
      },          
    ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _mySelectionTipoDoc;
  List<Map> dataTipoDoc = [
    {"nom": "1", "id": "id 1"},
    {"nom": "2", "id": "id 2"},
    {"nom": "3", "id": "id 3"}
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButton(
              value: _mySelectionTipoDoc,
              isDense: true,
              hint: Text("Seleccione Tipo Documento"),
              items: dataTipoDoc.map((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(item['nom']),
                  value: item['id'].toString(),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (Val) {
                setState(() {
                  _mySelectionTipoDoc = Val;
                  print(_mySelectionTipoDoc);
                });
              },
              //value: _mySelection,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```